# How can a heatmap be made from bin edges and values for each bin stored in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have 2D bin edges defined in a Pandas dataframe using the `cut` function. I am trying to see how to convert these bin edges and various values for each bin into a heatmap.

I start with the iris dataset and make a `UMAP` projection of it such that I have `UMAP` x and y coordinates for each data point.

[image]

I use the `cut` function to convert this into grid cells which result in bin edges in x and y. Then I get the mean values of the features corresponding to each grid cell.

[image]

Now, how could one go from this to a heatmap, like maybe a Seaborn heatmap? Taking this feature by feature, the first one would be a heatmap of the `sepal length (cm)_mean` values for each 2D bin (`UMAP_x_bin`, `UMAP_y_bin`).

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import umap # pip install umap-learn

iris = load_iris()
iris_df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
iris_df['species'] = pd.Series(iris.target).map(dict(zip(range(3), iris.target_names)))

_umap = umap.UMAP().fit_transform(iris.data)
iris_df['UMAP_x'] = _umap[:,0]
iris_df['UMAP_y'] = _umap[:,1]
#iris_df.head()

# Define bins for UMAP_x and UMAP_y parameters
iris_df['UMAP_x_bin'] = pd.cut(iris_df['UMAP_x'], bins=25)
iris_df['UMAP_y_bin'] = pd.cut(iris_df['UMAP_y'], bins=25)
# Calculate the mean value for each bin.
for feature in ['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)']:
    iris_df[feature+'_mean_x'] = iris_df.groupby('UMAP_x_bin')[feature].transform('mean')
    iris_df[feature+'_mean_y'] = iris_df.groupby('UMAP_y_bin')[feature].transform('mean')
    iris_df[feature+'_mean'] = (iris_df[feature+'_mean_x']+iris_df[feature+'_mean_y'])/2
#iris_df.head()

features_trimmed = ['UMAP_x_bin',
                    'UMAP_y_bin',
                    'sepal length (cm)_mean',
                    'sepal width (cm)_mean',
                    'petal length (cm)_mean',
                    'petal width (cm)_mean']
iris_df = iris_df[features_trimmed]
iris_df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to convert the `IntervalIndex` columns to Single value columns.

```
iris_df .UMAP_x_bin= iris_df .UMAP_x_bin.apply(lambda x: x.mid)
iris_df .UMAP_y_bin= iris_df .UMAP_x_bin.apply(lambda x: x.mid)
```

Then you will have to interpolate the data on to a 2D grid of of values. 
You can use `scipy` for that.

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

points = np.c_[iris_df .UMAP_x_bin, iris_df .UMAP_y_bin]
values = iris_df ['sepal length (cm)_mean'].to_numpy()

# Choose the range appropriately.
gridx, gridy = np.mgrid[0:100, 0:100]

# interpolate.
data = griddata(points, values, (gridx, gridy), method = 'nearest')

# plot the heatmap
sns.heatmap(data)
```

> PS. Choose the grid range appropriately, according to the range of `UMap_x_bin` and `UMap_y_bin`